# How to change data as per the current user's login

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to implement a user login system using Angular 6 for a stock management system. The user credentials are stored in the database which I'm able to pull into a component (login) and validate them. Upon successful login, I'm routing the page to the User component. Now I want to be able to show specific data for each user preserving the view of the component. Any direction as to how to implement this would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: One possible way would be to use a filter pipe to limit what is shown to each user. https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c

Comment: Just as for any other component displaying data: you send an HTTP request to the server, the server sends back the data, and the component displays them. The server should be able to find the current user in the request, from a cookie or a header (that depends on how your login works).

Comment: @Mathias: That is very neat hack. Will check that. Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned by others, the really right way to do things is to call the backend with the user's credentials to get data only they should see. But if you just want to limit what non-private data a user sees, a pipe filter might be a good tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is your backend to serve you user specific info when you request data from the backend.

When you make an HTTP request the backend should be able to determine who the user is based on the user cookie (I assume you have some kind of user cookie / header).

Then when the frontend makes a getData() HTTP request, the backend responds with the appropriate data for the user.

When you add POST or update PUT new data into the database, triggered by HTTP requests, the server will store the new or updated data in the database. When you do a subsequent GET you will GET the latest data.